# Как отформатировать строку средствами c#

Tags: c#, строки, htmlagilitypack

ребята, получил SelectSingleNode в переменную типа string вот в таком виде

```
Вес 470
Область печати 90 
Размер 60
```

как форматнуть строки, но уже с разметкой вот в таком виде?

```
<span class="a">Вес</span> <span class="b">470</span>
<span class="a">Область печати</span> <span class="b">90 </span>
<span class="a">Размер</span><span class="b"> 60 </span>
```

Comment: Откуда получил? В HTML они изначально в другом формате записаны?

Comment: если вернуть InnerHtml то изначальная разметка такая <li><span>Вес</span> 470</li> ...

Answer (score 1):

Ну например так:

```
var strings = new[] { "Вес 470", "Область печати 90", "Размер 60" };
var processed =
    from s in strings
    let idx = s.LastIndexOf(' ')
    select $"<span class=\"a\">{s.Substring(0, idx)}</span> <span class=\"b\">{s.Substring(idx + 1)}</span>";
```

Comment: а что если текст этот не двумерный массив а просто сплошным текстом типа string ShortDescr

Comment: @Den: тогда не `strings`, а `ShortDescr.Split('\n')`?

Comment: Так и сделал... получил три объекта со строками в переменную processed.. может подскажите как все это дело запихнуть в переменную string res без пробелов одной строчкой... Что бы добить так сказать

Comment: пробелы между объектами соответственно... всего три объекта в перечислении

Comment: @Den: Ну, чтобы склеить строки, используйте `string.Concat`. Или `string.Join`, если хотите вставить между строками что-то.

Comment: так, а как тот метод к перечислению применить?

Comment: @Den: `string.Concat(processed)`?